No silhouette on the character
Blender 4.2.1

Why doesn't my character get a silhouette from the rim light placed?
Cycles:

EEVEE:



It's not that your character isn't lit. If you turned around your character, you would see the back side is fine:

If the walls near your character seem to be the only ones lit from your camera viewpoint, it's because from that viewpoint we see faces that are somewhat oriented towards the light, whereas all the faces of your characters visible from the camera are turned away from the light, so there's not much to see.
But that's not all.
Your light is far away, and of a huge size, so the emitted light will be very diffuse and most will die out before reaching anything.
All the light that could go past your character's back, and then bounce off the surrounding environment and back to its face to light it up, is instead absorbed by a pure black emission shader on a fake ground:

And to top it all off, your character and environment are all basically cubes. So only 90° angles and 6 faces to catch light. You will not have many chances to light anything correctly with only one light.
So, you could go multiple routes here:
A) get the light closer and/or smaller to concentrate it on your subject. Or even add more light on the front side.

B) You could also just make the fake ground not a black hole. Or even remove it entirely and let the surroundings tint the light naturally:

If you need to keep a light somewhat sharp that only lights  up the rim of your character, you need to understand a bit more about how the physics of it works.
Your light needs to be smaller, otherwise you won't get a thin rim but a wide and diffuse mush. You need your light closed for the rays of such tiny light to reach out to the character. You need it angled the right way relative to your character. You need to shape the light so that it lights up the way you want.

